# Chicken/egg: does rails call a layout for a view, or a view from a layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I've been going through rails tutorials and I'm trying to understand what happens when a controller transitions to rendering a view. Setting aside models for this discussion, when a controller does its work for some_view, and the layout that will yield to some_view is the standard application.html.erb layout, what is actually happening here? Does the controller call the view, and then somehow the view calls the layout and the layout yields to the view? Or does the controller look for a suitable layout and then the layout intelligently yields to the view? Somehow the action within the controller and the suitable view and layout get paired up, but it isn't clear to me what the actual chain of actions is.

Comment: Have you had a read thru this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Yes, but I may have overlooked a concise description of the chain of events, which is what I'm seeking.

Comment: I think I'm looking for something like: "Rails looks for a view by the same name, calls the standard layout if no specific layout for that view exists, and the layout will yield to the view." This seems like what is happening, but in truth I can't tell if it's a layout lookup for a view that is in play, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are called from the controller. So for instance posts_controller index action will look in the views folder with the same name as the controller then look for the template with the same name as the action... app/views/posts/index.html.erb. This you already know.

Similarly it will by default look in the app/views/layouts folder for a layout with the same name as the controller... in this case it will look for app/views/layouts/posts.html.erb. It if does not find a file by this name it will default to app/views/layouts/application.html.erb as the default layout template.

The Rails magic will put the two together, with the index template going into the <%= yield %> area.

Comment: This answers my question, so thanks. It seemed somehow like the view was calling the layout, but the layout yields to the view. I will accept that there is Rails magic going on here, but the decision tree you described makes determinative sense, and that's a useful thing.

Comment: If you really want to peel away the onion take a look directly at the Rails source code. Rails is actually a conglomeration of 11 different Ruby gems. Layouts is part of the Action_View gem. You can see the details on github https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/layouts.rb